# Java BorderLayout.add not working each time

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I am creating a tabbed pane with tabs in the WEST or a borderlayout and the content in the middle. This is working great the first time the menu item is click setting the content in the pane I want. But once I have clicked a menu item once, that menu item with no longer repopulate the pane in the middle. Below is my set active function;

```
public void setActive()
{
    panelShowLocation.setAllMenuItemsAsInActive();
    active = true;
    setBackground(color_panelHover);
    menuText.setForeground(color_textHover);
    panelShowLocation.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //content.setVisible(true);
    panelShowLocation.revalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
panelShowLocation.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panelShowLocation.revalidate();
```

When you add a component to the panel the existing component is not removed.

Swing painting logic paints the last component added first. So the newly added component gets painted, but then the old components gets painted over top of the newly added component

So you need logic like:

```
panel.remove( theOldPanel );
panel.add(theNewPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The other option is to use a `CardLayout`. The CardLayout allows you to add multiple components to the same panel. Only one of the components is ever visible at the same time. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thank buddy. Got it to work based on your answer.